# Use Vue as NPM in basic project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm currently learning about npm and have npm installed Vue.js. However, this does not work when I try to use create a simple vue instance from my view. It works however when I enter a CDN link in the script source.

So this works:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
//This works fine
```

```
<script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
//This does NOT work
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12"
  }
```

So what am I missing in order to get the vue from the node_modules folder?

Comment: You need something like `webpack`, please learn about it

Answer (score 0):

You don't use relative paths with `node_modules`.

Try using an `import` statement:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

Or better yet, use the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and run `vue create <project-name>`. This way you can use Single-File-Components and all the scaffolding is handled for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Where should I use the import statement? When I simply enter it above my vue instance, it gives me the following msg: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: You can either add an attribute to the script tag: `type="module"`, or create a separate `.js` file and link to that file instead.